# How I can find the most resource-intensive queries that has ever run in my database and use a specific table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

In my database I want to check whether my idea on an improvement upon table schema works. Therefore I want so look which are the heaviest select queries ever run into our database and use a specific table that I want to do the changes.

My idea is to check the speed and database load of our heaviest queries in my database, then do the schema changes (or possible query refactoring as well) and rerun them so I can benchmark my idea with real data.

Hence I can have a proof that my changes actually improve search speed.

So how I can search which queries upon a postgresql RDS instance even run and how heavy they are?

Comment: [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.38.6) is probably the best you can get. No idea if you install that on RDS

Comment: Can you enable CSV logging and run pgBadger?